# In Russian, which preposition to use to say "Don't be late for lunch"?

Tags: словоупотребление, предлоги

> Вы, **к обеду** не **опоздайте**.
>
> Вы, **на обед** не **опоздайте**.
>
> Вы, **в обед** не **опоздайте**.

I assume the use of "с" is out of the question, but I'm wavering between these three. Are they nuanced somehow?

Incidentally, am I correct in thinking that "запоздать" cannot be used in this context?

Comment: one thing for sure, comma after `вы` is redundant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's either **не опоздайте к обеду** (in case both are supposed to meet at the lunch), or **на обед не опоздайте** (as a reminder to another person that they were planning to have a lunch *somewhere else*). The pronoun **вы** is not necessary and even may sound *unfriendly* (***вы*** на обед не опоздайте can express an actual desire to get rid of somebody's presence). **В обед** usually means **within the lunch break** and therefore doesn't fit an expression about being late.

Answer (score 3):

First, comma after `ты` or `вы` is rude, and colloquial. `Вы, ...` is short for `Эй вы, ...`.

> Вы к обеду не опоздайте.

This implies they should appear at lunch time.

> Вы на обед не опоздайте.

This implies they should appear at the lunch.

> Вы в обед не опоздайте.

This makes no sense.

Comment: #3 can mean "Don't be late _during_ the lunch time." Like "You can be late at any time, but not during the lunch time". Such communicative situation is not typical, but still possible.

Answer (score 1):

In real use, there definitely exists a nuance between using perfect and imperfect in such cases.

"Не опоздайте" (perf.) is sort of bit less polite reminder to not be late than "не опаздывайте" (imperf.), even if both of those are used with "пожалуйста". "Less polite" because it sort of implies the possibility of persons addressed to be late.

This nuance, however, vanishes in less formal conversation.

Pronoun isn't usually used in such phrases, just "не опаздывайте к обеду, пожалуйста" would do. Names, however, could be used.

Pronoun with full stop (written with comma) is right out, that's an equivalent to "hey you", just like @user31264 says.